# Make a column by two columns and conditions of the third column

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a dataset like this:

```
structure(list(INDEX1 = c(60L, 83L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 54L, 27L), 
    status = c("Y", "N", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "Y"), index2 = c(12L, 
    11L, 12L, 14L, 17L, 11L, 8L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

```
 INDEX1 status  index2
 60   Y         12
 83   N         11
 10   Y         12
 11   Y         14
 11   N         17
 54   N         11
 27   Y         8
```

I want to make a column (`index3`) that keep values of `index1` if `status =="Y"` and add the values of `index2` if `status=="N"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `ifelse/case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   mutate(index3 = case_when(status == "Y" ~ INDEX1, TRUE ~ index2))
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `fcase` with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dt)[, index3 := fcase(status == "Y", INDEX1, status == "N", index2)]
```

**Output**

```
   INDEX1 status index2 index3
1:     60      Y     12     60
2:     83      N     11     11
3:     10      Y     12     10
4:     11      Y     14     11
5:     11      N     17     17
6:     54      N     11     11
7:     27      Y      8     27
```

Answer (score 2):

From your statement:

> ... keep values of index1 if status =="Y" and add the values of index2 if status=="N"

I infer `INDEX1` if "Y", and `INDEX1+index2` if "N". From that, base R options:

```r
with(zz, INDEX1 + index2*(status == "N"))
# [1] 60 94 10 11 28 65 27

## alternatively
with(zz, INDEX1 + ifelse(status == "N", index2, 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R we can use `ifelse` like below

```
> transform(df, index3 = ifelse(status == "Y", INDEX1, index2))
  INDEX1 status index2 index3
1     60      Y     12     60
2     83      N     11     11
3     10      Y     12     10
4     11      Y     14     11
5     11      N     17     17
6     54      N     11     11
7     27      Y      8     27
```